# How to retrieve multiple values from a JSON object

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm working on a mobile application using Flutter.

I'm new to JSON. How do I retrieve multiple values from a JSON object?

```
body: new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
   new ListTile(
    title: new Text("$(_jsondata['name'])"),// json object calling
   ), 
  ]
 );
```

) got the values but now i want to call multiple values like `desc`, `url`, `id` other fields. I tried `$(_jsondata['name']['desc'])` but unable to achieve.

Comment: Where do you want the other fields to go?

Comment: Add your JSON object structure as well.

Comment: `new Text("name : $(_jsondata['name']) url : $(_jsondata['url'])")`

Comment: @ Raouf Rahiche  Thanks I got it.

Comment: @RaoufRahiche Make it an answer then.

Comment: glad to hear that . done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `_jsondata` is Map is String and dynamic to get the value of the field use it's name like this `_jsondata['name']` and do the same for other fields `_jsondata['url']`

- consider reading [this](https://flutter.io/json/) article from the documentation demonstrate
  how deserialization works in flutter